# Prove Quotient Group Isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G = (\mathbb{C} - \{0\}, \cdot)$, a subgroup $U = \{x+yi \mid x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$. Use the Fundamental Theorem to show that $G/(\mathbb{R}_{> 0},\cdot)$ is isomorphic to $U$ where $\mathbb{R}_{> 0}$ denotes the positive reals.

I am struggling to find the correct mapping from $G$ to $U$ that results in the the kernel being the nonnegative reals under multiplication. I'm hoping to get help with this mapping then I can show it is a homomorphism and onto and can use the Fundamental Theorem.

Comment: [Here are some tips on how to format math on this site.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Thank you I'll keep than in mind for next time

Comment: Yes I mis-typed

Comment: Hint: so under the mapping from $G$ to $U$, any two complex numbers that lie on the circle $U$ get mapped to $1$. What property do all those numbers have in common?

Comment: Okay, here's a hint: a nonzero complex number $z = x + iy$ can be written in polar form as $z = r e^{i \theta}$ where $r = |z| = x^2 + y^2$.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not extremely familiar with polar coordinates

Comment: All right, here's another way to think about it.  Say you have a vector $v$ in the plane.  How can you find a unit vector (i.e., of length $1$) that has the same direction as the original vector $v$?

Answer (score 1):

Every complex number $z \in \mathbb{C}$ can be written in the form $z=re^{i\theta}$ where $r=|z|$ and $\theta$ is its principal argument, $0 \leq \theta < 2\pi$.

Define $\psi:G \rightarrow U$ by $re^{i\theta} \mapsto e^{i\theta}$. Thus $\psi$ is an homomorphism, is onto and its kernel is $(\mathbb{R}_{> 0},\cdot)$.

Writting $z=x+iy$, then $\displaystyle \psi (z) = \psi(x+iy)=\frac{x+iy}{|x+iy|}.$ If $z$ is real and positive, i.e, $y=0$ and $x>0$, then $\displaystyle \psi(z)=\frac{x}{|x|}=1$.

First we prove that $\psi$ is an homomorphism. Let $z=re^{i\theta}$ and $w=se^{i\phi}$ in $G$. Thus 
\begin{equation*}
\psi(re^{i\theta}\cdot se^{i\phi})=\psi(rse^{i(\theta+\phi)})=e^{i(\theta+\phi)}=e^{i\theta}e^{i\phi}=\psi(re^{i\theta})\psi(se^{i\phi}).
\end{equation*}
Now, $\psi$ is onto because every element of $U$ has the form $e^{i\theta}$, so in fact $\psi$ is the identity in $U$.

Finally we find the kernel. Suppose that $z=re^{i\theta} \in G$ is such that $\psi(z)=1$. Thus $e^{i\theta}=1$. As $0 \leq \theta < 2\pi$, then $\theta = 0$ and therefore $z$ is a real positive number. So $\ker \psi = \mathbb{R}_{> 0}$.

Comment: Does $|x+iy|=x^2+y^2$? Sorry I'm not very familiar with this stuff...

Comment: Don't worry. $|x+iy|=+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Comment: Okay.... I've been trying to work with that and am having trouble expressing the kernel and finishing out the proof of showing its a homomorphism and onto.

Comment: I'm not sure what the identity element is of U...

Comment: I´m editing. The identity of $U$ is the same of $G$, is 1.

Comment: Okay great. I think I may have something using that.